# Problem putting using %s in a MySQL command

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to automate (by using python scripting) the ability to create a MySQL role, but for some reason I am unable to put my string variable into mysql command. This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import  mysql.connector
from    mysql.connector import errorcode 


# Open database connection
try:

        serverHostName='localhost'
        userName='root'
        passwd='password'
        databaseName='mysql'
        roleName='reader'

        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=serverHostName,
        database=databaseName, 
        user=userName, 
        password=passwd)

        cursor=cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
        dropRole="""DROP ROLE IF EXISTS %s """

        print(dropRole, roleName)
        #cursor.execute(dropRole, roleName)
        #cnx.commit()



except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
  print("You have successfully disconnected from your MySQL database")
```

what comes out is the following:

```
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS %s  reader
You have successfully disconnected from your MySQL database
```

If anyone can explain to me why %s and the reader is showing up in my print line that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call a formatting operator to subsitute `roleName` into the string, so it's just printing the format string. Use the `%` operator to perform formatting.

```
print(dropRole % roleName)
```